# Can you mix up the language stack in windows 8 Metro?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

can you do HTML/C# , or HTML/C++ , or XAML/Javascript in Windows 8 Metro?

I know that i could have a HTML/JS that could include a WinRT .winMD "DLL" that happens to be C# or C++ and call it from the JS, but is there any other way?

Also i presume that i could make a WinMD Dll containing Javascript functions and call it from a XAML/C# or XAML/C++ but are these the only ways?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? IMO it's a bad idea.

Comment: its not a matter of whether i want to or not,whether its a good idea or not but understanding the boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all combinations are allowed in the 3x3 matrix of language/rendering technology.

- HTML/JS/CSS can only use JS.
- XAML can only use .NET (C#/VB) and C++.
- DirectX can only use C++.

You can create Win RT components using C++ or .NET (C#/VB) but not JavaScript. You can use those components from a JavaScript app as well as a .NET or C++ app.

See documentation for creating C#/VB modules [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sounds legitimate, but a link to the source would be nice. Anyone?

Comment: Added a link to the documentation on creating modules in C#/VB

Answer (score 2):

winmd is the only way to use c#/c++ in javascript. 
There is no support for javascript in c#/c++.